# Can't make form controls transparent

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, form-control

Is there a way to make form controls transparent?  Actually, none of my inputs or buttons adhere to my css styling.  I want to make the ion-input transparent and change the color on the ion-button but it's not adhering to my .css

I'd like for the background image to fill the input fields as well and make the hyperlink text buttons white.

```
ion-content {
      --background: #fff url("../../../assets/img/login-image.jpg") no-repeat center center / cover;
     }
form {
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  ion-button {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
  }
}

p {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #d2d2d2;
}

ion-label {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

ion-input {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}

ion-content {
  ion-button{
  .linkbuttons {
    color: white !important;
   }
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-content class="background">
<form [formGroup]="loginForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Email</ion-label>
    <ion-input
      formControlName="email"
      type="email"
      placeholder="Your email address"
      [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls['email'].valid &&
      loginForm.controls['email'].touched"
    >
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item
    class="error-message"
    *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['email'].valid &&
       loginForm.controls['email'].touched"
  >
    <ion-label>Please enter a valid email address.</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input
      formControlName="password"
      type="password"
      placeholder="Your password"
      [class.invalid]="!loginForm.controls['password'].valid&& loginForm.controls['password'].touched"
    >
    </ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item
    class="error-message"
    *ngIf="!loginForm.controls['password'].valid
      && loginForm.controls['password'].touched">
    <ion-label>Your password needs more than 6 characters.</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-button (click)="loginUser(loginForm)" expand="block" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
    Log In
  </ion-button>
</form>

  <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" class="linkbuttons" routerLink="/signup">
    Create a new account
  </ion-button>

  <ion-button expand="block" fill="clear" class="linkbuttons" routerLink="/reset-password">
    I forgot my password
  </ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ionic 5**

I have done it using `color="transparent"` on `ion-item`

```
  <ion-item color="transparent">
       

   </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `background-color: transparent`, try `opacity: 0.5` instead ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background of the `ion-input` with the custom variable `--background`.

```
ion-input{
  --background: transparent;
}
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#css-custom-properties

`ion-button` works the  same way:

```
ion-button{   
  --background: ...; 
}
```

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/button